# Simple Vector Analysis

Tags: vectors

Hello im having a problem with the question below. What i dont understand is the highlighted parts? What is a vector component and unit vector? 
[image: Question]

Comment: It is difficult to follow the screenshot without much context, but to answer the questions, a unit vector is a vector with norm equal to $1$.  A few examples of unit vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ with the usual euclidean norm would be $(1,0,0), (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)$ and $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$, but any vector pointing to a spot on the unit sphere works.  Often-times in physics textbooks, a vector which is unit length has this fact emphasized by writing it with a hat character, like $\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{z}$ etc...

Comment: As for a vector component (*in the direction of another vector*), it is referring to the magnitude of the inner product of the original vector with the unit vector in the desired direction.